# Eclipse error com.avaje.ebean.EbeanServer not resolved

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse I have an error on my top blank line and I cant get rid of it. Here's my code (I am making a bukkit plugin):

```java
//this is where I get the error
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        new EventHandler(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {

    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("BLANK") && sender instanceof Player) {

            Player player = (Player) sender;

            return true;

        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

I can't find anyway around it. Please help.

Comment: Try to delete the blank

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing your package name. Try this instead:

```
package my.package.name;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        new EventHandler(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {

    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("BLANK") && sender instanceof Player) {

            Player player = (Player) sender;

            return true;

        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Remember to replace `my.package.name` with your package name.